# Summing GroupBy results into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a list of objects:

```
class myObj{   
  string type;   
  int amount;
}
```

How do I group by the "type" field, sum up the amount under each type, then put the result into a dictionary?  Here is what I got:

```
myList
  .GroupBy(x=>x.type)
  .ToDictionary(
    x=>x.Key, 
    x=>x.GetEnumerator().Sum(y=>y.amount)
  );
```

The error I get is this:

```
IEnumerator does not contain a definition for Sum
```

Be very careful it say "IEnumerator" and not IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `GetEnumerator()`, just use `Sum()` method in the group:

```
myList.GroupBy(x => x.type)
      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => y.amount));
```

`Sum()` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`, not of `IEnumerator<T>`. Since `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` inherits from `IEnumerable<TElement>` you can use *Linq* extensions in this type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need a collection object for you class myObj. It is easier to use a List<> object like the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<myObj> objs = new List<myObj>();
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = objs.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.type, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.amount).Sum());
        }
    }
    public class myObj
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
myList
  .GroupBy(x=>x.type)
  .ToDictionary(
    x=>x.Key, 
    x=>x.Sum(y=>y.amount)
  );
```

`IGrouping<Key, T>` is `IEnumerable<T>`